How do I click on the input button inside a form with Selenium and Python?
I have this form and I need to click on the input type button with the value = CASTRO SALVADOR. I'm using Python and Selenium.
<form name="seleccionaEmpresaForm" action="setearContribuyente.do">
<table width="50%" align="center">
<tbody><tr><td height="5"></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><b>Seleccione la Empresa a representar:</b></td></tr>
<tr><td height="5"></td></tr>
<tr>
   <td align="center">
           <input type="hidden" name="idContribuyente" id="idcontribuyente">
               <input type="button" class="btn_empresa ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="width:100%" value="CASTRO SALVADOR" onclick="document.getElementById('idcontribuyente').value='0';document.seleccionaEmpresaForm.submit();" role="button">
   </td>
</tr>
<tr><td height="5"></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>

Below my code, you will find different ways I tried to select the input type button.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

# Configura el driver de Selenium para Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Navega a la página de login del sistema de AFIP
driver.get("https://auth.afip.gov.ar/contribuyente_/login.xhtml?action=SYSTEM&system=admin_mono")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "F1:username"))).send_keys("xxxxxx")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "F1:btnSiguiente"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "F1:password"))).send_keys("xxxxx")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "F1:btnIngresar"))).click()

# Espera para asegurar que la sesión se haya iniciado correctamente
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains("monotributo.afip.gob.ar"))

# Navega a la página de facturación
driver.get("https://monotributo.afip.gob.ar/app/Facturacion.aspx")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "bBtn1")))

# Hace clic en el botón inicial en la página de facturación
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "bBtn1"))).click()

# Espera hasta que el elemento sea visible y no solo presente:
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='CASTRO SALVADOR']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
button.click()

I also try:
boton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn_empresa[value='CASTRO SALVADOR']")
boton.click()

I also try:
boton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn_empresa.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all")
boton.click()

Update. I just try:
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn_empresa' and @value='CASTRO SALVADOR']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

But I had this terminal error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/salvacastro/Desktop/afip.py", line 31, in <module>
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn_empresa' and @value='CASTRO SALVADOR']")
  File "/Users/salvacastro/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 748, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "/Users/salvacastro/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/salvacastro/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@class='btn_empresa' and @value='CASTRO SALVADOR']; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:193:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:511:5
dom.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/shared/DOM.sys.mjs:136:16


did you just share your credentials? immediately change your credentials!!

Tks, I just updated.

did you change your password? you need to do that, edits are still visible in the history.

JavaScript Execution:
You can click the button using JavaScript
try:
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn_empresa' and @value='CASTRO SALVADOR']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)


I update the question with the terminal error

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@class='btn_empresa' and @value='CASTRO SALVADOR']; For documentation on this error, please visit: link

I just update the locator with the browser’s devtools console or use a browser extension like SelectorHub and I also use a proper Waiting Strategy. I update the question with my code.

I just update the question.
